# How to search for a pattern in a line and print data which is present after that pattern in that line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have file which has uneven lines as below:

```
jacktyutu/ABC/uyiyi/yyuiyiu/1.java
adhjasgdhg/gsdjgf/ABC/sdfhgsdfj/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/2.java
adhjasgdhg/01/ABC/sdfhgs/213/j/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/3.java
sd/asd/asd/ABC/sdjg/76/987/4.java
```

From the above file I want to search for the pattern `ABC` from each line and print the rest of the data from that line for ex

My output should be as below:

```
uyiyi/yyuiyiu/1.java
sdfhgsdfj/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/2.java
sdfhgs/213/j/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/3.java
sdjg/76/987/4.java
```

How to achieve this in shell script or with `awk` and `sed`?

Comment: wow! 5 BASH/Unix experts answering your question, you question is really very lucky :)

Comment: What would you want to happen if a line did not contain "ABC"? What if a line contained "FOOABC" or "ABCFOO"? What if ABC appeared twice? Show some edge cases like those in your input and the expected output associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU Grep`:

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=ABC/).*" file
uyiyi/yyuiyiu/1.java
sdfhgsdfj/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/2.java
sdfhgs/213/j/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/3.java
sdjg/76/987/4.java
```

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'ABC/' '{print $2}' file
uyiyi/yyuiyiu/1.java
sdfhgsdfj/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/2.java
sdfhgs/213/j/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/3.java
sdjg/76/987/4.java
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's%.*ABC/%%' file
uyiyi/yyuiyiu/1.java
sdfhgsdfj/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/2.java
sdfhgs/213/j/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/3.java
sdjg/76/987/4.java
```

Comment: LOL, awk command will have useless empty line, and sed command does not output for search pattern "ABC" only.

Comment: @BMW I have been doing this much longer than you and I'm quite aware of the output for all the commands for given sets of input. All 3 work fine for the question that was actually asked.. If the OP didn't use representative data that's to bad.

Comment: I have to give -1 for this type of answer. Merry Christmas

Comment: @BMW You really are very sad.. It's a shame. Fedorqui answers is same as mine without the grep, no downvote for him?

Answer (score 1):

> From the above file I want to search for the pattern ABC from each
>   line and print the rest of the data from that line for ex...

I would do:

```
 grep -Po '.*?ABC/\K.*' file
```

this works if one line containing multiple `ABC/`, it picks only the rest stuff after the **1st** `ABC/`. if it is required.

see test:

```
kent$  cat f
jacktyutu/ABC/uyiyi/yyuiyiu/1.java
adhjasgdhg/gsdjgf/ABC/sdfhgsdfj/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/2.java
adhjasgdhg/01/ABC/sdfhgs/213/j/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/3.java
sd/asd/asd/ABC/sdjg/76/987/4.java
foo/ABC/___here/ABC/comes again

kent$  grep -Po '.*?ABC/\K.*' f
uyiyi/yyuiyiu/1.java
sdfhgsdfj/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/2.java
sdfhgs/213/j/sdjfhsd/sdfkjhsdkf/3.java
sdjg/76/987/4.java
___here/ABC/comes again
```

Comment: Or `grep -Po ... || echo Not found` to cover the case of no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have one ABC in each line

```
perl -F"\/ABC\/" -ane 'print $F[1];' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory `bash` version:

```
found_something=false
while read line
do
  [[ "${line}" =~ ABC/ ]] && echo "${line#*ABC/}" && found_something=true
done < file
${found_something} || echo "I didn't find any lines matching ABC/"
```

Edit: added a few lines to handle the case of the target string not being present...

Comment: what if the file does not contain pattern ABC ??  in that case i want to print a message and exit .

Answer (score 0):

A **perl** oneliner:

```
    perl -e "/ABC/;print $';"
```

_

```
    print $`
```

prints everything before the match, and

```
    print $&
```

prints the matched characters, useful if you are matching against a pattern (Regular Expression).

A modern version of **sed** or **awk** may have the special $ variables, but I have not seen any.